# Express a point as an affine combination of another two points(3D collinearity)

Tags: affine-geometry

So, given the points `A(1,2,2)`, `B(2,4,2)` and `C(3,6,2)` I have to show that they are collinear.
If they are collinear then I must express one point as an affine combination of the other two points.
I have searched everywhere and I can't find an explicit solve of such geometry problems, can you guys show me how I must proceed?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would like to find $x$ and $y$ such that

$$C = xA + yB$$

and

$$x + y = 1$$

To do this, we can simply pick the first coordinates of all three points. We then have the following equality:

$$1x + 2y = 3$$

Putting this together with $x + y = 1$, we have $x = -1$ and $y = 2$, and since you can verify that

$$C = -A + 2B$$

then $C$ is an affine combination of $A$ and $B$ and thus all three points are collinear.

(of course if you only care for collinearity, there are easier tests such as the cross product test).

Comment: Thanks, I now understand how this works, greatly appreciate it, I will vote up and accept the answer.

Comment: quick question, how do I check that `C=-A+2B` ?

Comment: Just compute $-A + 2B $ and see if it's equal to C?

Comment: I understand, but what do I do in this case `A(1,0,0)`,`B(1,1,1)`,`C(1,3,3)` ? It won't work, and they are collinear.

Comment: You have to pick a coordinate that's different. In this case use the y coordinates